# Redis user uses high cpu

Tags: redis

My server configuration is  `4 GB Memory / 80 GB Disk / SGP1 - CentOS 7.6 x64.`

My redis version  `Redis server v=4.0.11 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-4.0.3 bits=64 build=4caa563e40a30492`

This server is dedicated to Redis only

[image]

From the picture you can see there is a user called Redis and under is user there are two processes which is causing high CPU uses. I have no idea what is the purposes of these two commands. Is this harmful to my server should I keep them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sysupdate and networkservice seem to be malicious services running in your system. Maybe somehow hackers got into your system and upload some scripts which are taking too much of your capacities. Most probably they are mining. So follow the below steps

1. stop that services
2. backup your redis file
3. restart your server
4. you can reinstall your redis
5. better to hire some consultant for hardening your redis server